# Обособлять ли приложение?

Tags: пунктуация

Его вторая жена, красавица, умница – вы её только что видели – вышла за него, когда уже он был стар (Ч.);

Почему после *умница* нет запятой? Разве это не обособленное приложение к слову *жена*?

Answer (score 1):

Если бы и нужно было обособлять приложение "красавица, умница", то лишь после слова "видели", но здесь тире поглощает запятую

Comment: Не пойму, почему запятая после слова "видели" должна стоять? ) Ведь перед первым тире ставится запятая, если этого требует структура первой части основного предложения.

Answer (score 1):

В моём варианте "Дяди Вани" это предложение с запятой после "видели", вот на этих сайтах тоже:http://www.licey.net/russian/upr/answers2_4
http://public-library.narod.ru/Chekhov.Anton/dyadyav.html
http://thelib.ru/books/chehov_a_p/dyadya_vanya-read.html

Видимо, во времена Чехова знак был факультативен.Тогда пунктуация была факультативна довольно часто. Виктор объяснил верно, пауза уже обозначена с помощью тире, запятая показалась Чехову излишней. У меня издание новое,по современным правилам.При переизданиях иногда пунктуацию правят, а может,Чехов и сам поправил, изданий было много.